# Get empty graph in Spyder Python

Tags: python, networkx, spyder

I tried this code in Spyder (python 3.9)

```
import networkx as nx
cg= nx.complete_graph(10, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
nx.draw(cg)
```

but I got an empty graph in the plot console.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to reproduce the problem:

[image]

*Moving some of the information from the comments below:*

Since it had previously shown the graph and now it doesn't and even Matplotlib graphs show up blank and you are running 5.1.5 (which had a lot of other issues), here are some steps to update Spyder itself:

Go to Anaconda Navigator and add conda-forge to your list of sources (Spyder is not being updated on the default channel now):
[image]

Go to the Spyder item in that window and click Upgrade (it's grayed out on my setup because I already have the latest version):
[image]

Comment: Are you running the entire script using the play button, or are you only running the last line or something?

Comment: I try to upgrade the version As mentioned
but not working the upgrade

Comment: @NAS Please see my edit, hopefully that will help!

Comment: from where i can add conda-frog?

Comment: @NAS Click on the "Channels" button that's immediately over the dialog box in the first picture (to the right of where it says "Applications on"

Comment: I try to add conda-frog from channel button , but i can not because the add button is disable. but when I change the root to spyder -env i got the spyder version 5.2.2 but I cant lunch it

Comment: @NAS What is the error message that it gives you when you are unable to launch it?  The button shouldn't be grayed out if you select one of your environments (in this case, base).  If you don't have a lot already setup in this environment, your best bet may be to just reinstall Anaconda.